# “Flow” between computers (Logitech mouse) DLP

Tags: dlp

From a DLP perspective, does anyone know what DLP controls to block or monitor this [Logitech Flow](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options/page/flow-multi-device-control)?

Answer (score 2):

DLP generally works at the filesystem level, scanning files when opened and/or written to disk.  Files copied onto a system using Logitech Flow will trigger DLP at the same points as usual; DLP cares about filesystem operations and not about the method (network, Flow, carrier pigeon, ...) used to get the file in place for interaction with the filesystem.

Comment: Ok let me ask it this way, we block USB storage, network storage like Dropbox and such. What controls if not using say 802.1x and someone for some reason got admin to install flow on work PC and personal block this insider threat because of this really pretty cool enduser technology. I assume as the whitepaper was rather vague this is just using peer-to-peer over standard peer-to-peer ports 6881-6889 or HTTPS? I guess I could just fire up wireshark and answer most of my own questions I have. :)